# Can't change variable across Navigationviews

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I have a button that is supposed to change a variable in a different class, once changed, other NavigationViews reading this variable also need to change. If it helps, the variable that needs to be updated everywhere is a UIColor.

This is the button:

```
struct SettingsView: View {

@State private var colorToggle = 0
    
    func colorToggleButton() {
        // color toggle logic
        if colorToggle == 0 {
           colorToggle += 1
        }
        else if colorToggle == 1 {
            colorToggle -= 1
        }
    }
    
    func colorToggleLogic() {
        if colorToggle == 0 {
            viewModel.backgroundColor = .white
        }
        else if colorToggle == 1 {
            viewModel.backgroundColor = .orange
        }
    }


        Button(action: {
            colorToggleButton()
            colorToggleLogic()
        }, label: {
            Text("Color")
        }).offset(x: -5, y: 0)
}
```

This is the ViewModel where the backgroundColor variable is:

```
class VariableViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var backgroundColor: UIColor = .white
}
```

And this is where the variable need to be updated but isn't working for some reason when being changed:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  
    // variable for view model
@ObservedObject var viewModel = VariableViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
NavigationView {

ZStack {
  Color(viewModel.backgroundColor)
HStack {
                Spacer()
            NavigationLink(destination:
                SettingsView()
            ){
                Image(systemName: "gearshape.fill").font(.system(size: 25))
            }
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: It isn't working because you only seem to be calling a ZStack with the Color view in the `ContentView`, but nowhere else. Make sure that you are actually using the Color everywhere else.

Comment: @Todd, No the problem is that when the button changes the color to something else, it isn't updating in the ContentView.

Comment: This may not fit your requirements but perhaps you can use a State var to manage the color instead? State vars usually update normally. I can add an answer on a possible implementation of this if it works for you.

Comment: @Todd, but how would I make it update across all the files from one button?

Comment: @Todd thank you so much that worked, but quick question, I know have the issue that the color will only update if I excit and come back to the menu because the new variable needs to get passed through. Anything I can do about that so ut gets passed through without me having to leave settings and come back?

Comment: Which method did you use? The files or the State var? If it was the State var, then you can create another State var for the Settings View and use that for the background color. You should also add an `onAppear` to the settings view to assign `self.backgroundColor` to `parent.backgroundColor` if you choose to do this.

Comment: @Todd I choose to do @ State var option, can you elaborate on what you mean by creating a new variable

Comment: please look at my edited answer.

Comment: You can create a new parent in the third view of the type Second View and then you can use `parent.parent.backgroundColor`

Comment: @Todd Sorry can you elaborate on that?

Comment: you need to create a new @State var parent in the third view but make it of type Second View. For example let's say SecondView is named `HomeView` then in the third view, you can declare `@State var parent: HomeView` and then in the third view, you can call the background color using `parent.parent.backgroundColor`. This can be done for every view. `HomeView` is just an example. You would need to replace it with the actual name of your second view.

Comment: @Todd, I got it now, Thank you so much for your help. You don't even know how long I was trying to understand how to do this on my own...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an ObservableObject, you could try using a State var. You could try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  
    // variable for view model
@State var backgroundColor: Color = .white
    
    var body: some View {
NavigationView {

ZStack {
  Color(backgroundColor)
HStack {
                Spacer()
            NavigationLink(destination:
                SettingsView(parent: self)
            ){
                Image(systemName: "gearshape.fill").font(.system(size: 25))
            }
}
}
}
}
```

and you should update `SettingsView` to this:

```
struct SettingsView: View {

@State var parent: ContentView
@State private var colorToggle = 0
    
    func colorToggleButton() {
        // color toggle logic
        if colorToggle == 0 {
           colorToggle += 1
        }
        else if colorToggle == 1 {
            colorToggle -= 1
        }
    }
    
    func colorToggleLogic() {
        if colorToggle == 0 {
            parent.backgroundColor = .white
        }
        else if colorToggle == 1 {
            parent.backgroundColor = .orange
        }
    }


        Button(action: {
            colorToggleButton()
            colorToggleLogic()
        }, label: {
            Text("Color")
        }).offset(x: -5, y: 0)
}
```

This allows you to use the State var in `ContentView` everywhere. Similarly, you just need to add a State var called `parent` or something else of your choice that is of type `ContentView` so that you can access the backgroundColor property.

Another way that you could do this is by writing the color choice to a file and adding extra code in the views to process it.

For example:

```
struct SettingsView: View {

@State private var colorToggle = 0
    
    func colorToggleButton() {
        // color toggle logic
        if colorToggle == 0 {
           colorToggle += 1
        }
        else if colorToggle == 1 {
            colorToggle -= 1
        }
    }
    
    func colorToggleLogic() {
        if colorToggle == 0 {
            let url = FileManager.default.urls(for .documentsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("ColorSelection.txt")
            do {
                try "white".data(using: .utf8)!.write(to: url)
            }
            catch {
                //handle error
            }
        }
        else if colorToggle == 1 {
            let url = FileManager.default.urls(for .documentsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("ColorSelection.txt")
            do {
                try "orange".data(using: .utf8)!.write(to: url)
            }
            catch {
                //handle error
            }
        }
    }


        Button(action: {
            colorToggleButton()
            colorToggleLogic()
        }, label: {
            Text("Color")
        }).offset(x: -5, y: 0)
}
```

and in `ContentView` or any other view where you need the background color, you could add the following:

```
func processColor() {
    let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("ColorSelection.txt")
    do {
        let color = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        if String(data: color, encoding: .utf8)! == "white" {
            // set background to white
        }
        else {
            // set background to orange
        } 
    }
    catch {
        //handle error
    }
}
```

EDIT:

In response to one of the OP's comments asking how the Settings View can be updated without exiting and coming back, the following code can be used:

```
struct SettingsView: View {

@State var parent: ContentView
@State private var colorToggle = 0
@State var backgroundColor = .white

    func colorToggleButton() {
        // color toggle logic
        if colorToggle == 0 {
           colorToggle += 1
        }
        else if colorToggle == 1 {
            colorToggle -= 1
        }
    }

    func colorToggleLogic() {
        if colorToggle == 0 {
            parent.backgroundColor = .white
            self.backgroundColor = .white
        }
        else if colorToggle == 1 {
            parent.backgroundColor = .orange
            self.backgroundColor = .orange
        }
    }


        Button(action: {
            colorToggleButton()
            colorToggleLogic()
        }, label: {
            Text("Color")
        }).offset(x: -5, y: 0).onAppear {
            self.backgroundColor = parent.backgroundColor
        }
}
```

This will create a new variable that controls the background color in the Settings View itself so that there is no need to exit the view and re-enter.